# Android Checkbox for firefox,Chrome,IE8

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to use android checkboxes (styled with css and/or jQuery) on my project but I don't find nothing in order to help me with this. Something like a jQuery plugin or html/css template with some checkboxes. If someone cand help me with some links,because so far I don't found nothing :(.

thank's.

Answer (score 1):

Try uniform.js - http://uniformjs.com/

You can build your own theme for it which could look like the android theme.